# Syntax to figure out the y value for a particular x value in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Here's the problem statement:

Two non-linear inter-dependent, initial value first order differential equations were solved using NDSolve to yield an analytical solution. The solution was used to calculate another parameter, as a function of the same x value.

Let's say we have the ODEs as:

```
X'[t]=a*S[t]*X[t]/(b+S[t]
S'[t]=-a*S[t]*X[t]/(c(b+S[t])) where a,b,c are also known constants
X[0]=constant
S[0]=constant

soln = NDSolve[{X'[t]=a*S[t]*X[t]/(b+S[t],S'[t]=-a*S[t]*X[t]/(c(b+S[t])),X[0]=constant,S[0]=constant},{X,S},{t,0,50}]

    The solution is of the form
X-> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.0,50}},<>],S->InterpolationFunction[{{0.0,50}},<>}}

Now the new parameter is: Yvalue=(S[t]/.soln)+(X[t]/.soln)
```

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax to calculate Yvalue for an entered t value.
Ex- One needs to calculate Yvalue at t=0.1,0.56, 2.3 etc

Thank you for your time.

Regards, 
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

NDSolve demands that all parameters be given specific numeric values. If you assign values to a,b,c,X[0],S[0] and carefully match up all your parens and carefully use == versus = correctly, then this can work

```
In[1]:= a = 2; b = 3; c = 5;
   soln = NDSolve[{X'[t] == a*S[t]*X[t]/(b + S[t]), 
   S'[t] == -a*S[t]*X[t]/(c(b+S[t])), X[0]==7, S[0]==11}, {X,S}, {t,0,50}][[1]]

Out[2]= {X -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,50.}}, <>],
         S -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,50.}}, <>]}

In[3]:= Yvalue = S[t] + X[t] /. soln /. t -> 0.1

Out[3]= 18.9506

In[4]:= Yvalue = S[t] + X[t] /. soln /. t -> 0.56

Out[4]= 25.6919

In[5]:= Yvalue = S[t] + X[t] /. soln /. t -> 2.3

Out[5]= 61.9823
```

and even

```
In[6]:= Plot[S[t] + X[t] /. soln, {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {0, 70}]

Out[6]= ...PlotSnipped...
```